# Textbox won't update until method done

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox

I am trying to use a textbox to show Tasks completing.  Basically like how console application would show what is happening.

However the text in the textbox is only updating after Window_Loaded_1 has completed, then all the text gets displayed instead of in realtime.

xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="timelineTesting.Windows.CreateNewProject"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="CreateNewProject" Height="300" Width="579" Loaded="Window_Loaded_1">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LogData, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Grid>
```

C# code:

```
public partial class CreateNewProject : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _data;
    public String LogData
    {
        get
        {
            return _data;
        } 
        set
        {
            _data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LogData");
        }
    }

    public CreateNewProject()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;   
    }

    private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task t = new Task(() => Directory.CreateDirectory(this.ProjectName));

        LogData+="Starting new project creation...." + Environment.NewLine;
        LogData += "Creating project directory '" + ProjectName + "'....";
        try
        {
            t.Start();
            t.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogData += "Error:" + Environment.NewLine;
            LogData += ex.InnerException.ToString();
        }

        LogData+= "Done!" + Environment.NewLine;

        t = new Task(() => File.Copy(this.VideoFilePath, newVideoPath));
        LogData+= "Copying video file to project directory....";
        try
        {
            t.Start();
            t.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogData+= "Error:" + Environment.NewLine;
            LogData+= ex.InnerException.ToString();
        }

        LogData+= "Done!" + Environment.NewLine;
        // many more tasks
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is that `Wait` is blocking the GUI thread. The GUI can't update while it's busy waiting for your task.

Comment: @MattBurland, but I thought the Wait will block till the Task is done, when the Task is done the GUI should no longer be blocked.  Then adding to the LogData string should update the GUI till we Wait again. Why doesn't that happen?  I am not trying to add to the string till the Wait is over.

Comment: The UI needs to be able to process Paint messages for you to see the changes. You're not actually returning to the UI loop between the `Wait`s, so the UI can't repaint itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `await`:

```
private async void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Task t = Task.Run(() => Directory.CreateDirectory(this.ProjectName));
  LogData += "Starting new project creation...." + Environment.NewLine;
  LogData += "Creating project directory '" + ProjectName + "'....";
  try
  {
    await t;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    LogData += "Error:" + Environment.NewLine;
    LogData += ex.ToString();
  }

  LogData += "Done!" + Environment.NewLine;

  t = Task.Run(() => File.Copy(this.VideoFilePath, newVideoPath));
  LogData += "Copying video file to project directory....";
  try
  {
    await t;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    LogData += "Error:" + Environment.NewLine;
    LogData += ex.ToString();
  }

  LogData += "Done!" + Environment.NewLine;

  // many more tasks
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`t.Wait()` is a blocking call.  Meaning you are really not doing multi threading.  You start the task and then wait for it to complete.  What you should do is `await` for the task to complete.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) instead which has a ProgressChanged event which could update your textbox with a concurrent status.

See the article: [C# WPF: Threading, Control Updating, Status Bar and Cancel Operations Example All In One](http://omegacoder.com/?p=642) which provides an example.